# Boolean board game in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean, operators

Program should print out the given values in array1 and print the second array as true or false.

Array1 represents a boardgame where characters can stand at the different positions. The integers indicate how dangerous it is to stand at every position.

If the character finds itself at int 3, it is to be declared dead.
If you add the values of each neighbor(not including the current position) and the total value equals 15 or more, it is also to be declared dead.

dead = false (F)
alive = true (T)

So if the current position is 2 or 1 and the total value of every neighbor is less then 15, the character lives. The neighbors missing in the edge of the array is to be counted as 0.

How do i print this the same way as array1 but with boolean values of T or F?

totalavGrannar is the variable that should add all the neighbors total value.

My code so far:

```
     import java.util.Arrays;
     public class uppg10{
      public static void main(String[] args){


      int [][] array1 = {{1,1,2,3,3},
                         {2,1,1,2,3},
                         {3,2,2,1,2},
                         {3,3,3,3,3}};

      boolean [][] array2 = new boolean [4][5];

      int rows = array1.length;
      int cols = array1[0].length;

      int totalavGrannar = 0;

      array2 = new boolean[rows][cols];

      for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
       for (int col=0; col<cols; col++) {

       System.out.print(String.format("%4d", array1[row][col]));

        if ( ( (col+1) % cols ==0) && (col > 0))

        System.out.println();
       }
      }

      for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
       for (int col=0; col<cols; col++) {

       boolean trueorFalse;

       if (array1[row][col]<3) {
        trueorFalse = true;
        array2[row][col] = trueorFalse;
       }
       else{
         trueorFalse = false;
       }

       row = 1;
       col = 1;

       for(int offsetRow=row-1; offsetRow<=row+1; offsetRow++){
        for(int offsetCol=col-1; offsetCol<=col+1; offsetCol++){

           totalavGrannar += array1[offsetRow][offsetCol];

           boolean trueorFalse2;

           if (totalavGrannar<15) {
             trueorFalse2 = true;
             array2[row][col] = trueorFalse2;
           }

           else{
             trueorFalse2 = false;

           }

         }
        }

       }
      }

      for (int row=0; row<array2.length; row++) {
       for (int col=0; col<array2[row].length; col++) {

       System.out.print(String.format("%8s" , array2[row][col] ? "T" : "F"));

       if ( ( (col+1) % cols ==0) && (col > 0))

       System.out.println();

       }
      }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i print this the same way as array1 but with boolean values of T or F?

For your question you did it correct in your code.
Your code not work because you have few others problems:

1. In the second loop you override array2 values even if false(dead).
   you make him alive (set to true)

   ```
   if (totalavGrannar<15) {
       trueorFalse2 = true;
       array2[row][col] = trueorFalse2;
   }
   ```

   Also, you sum the position with all neighbors (total 9 cells instead of only 8 neighbors)

--> In solution I set condition to exclude the position itself.

2. Another problem is that when you sum neighbors you check equality to 15 per addition for updat (T/F). This is wasteful.
   --> You need to sum all and only then update value (T/F).
3. In the second loop you reset you loop condition to '1' so you have endless loop.
   --> I removed those lines.
4. You forgot to reset totalavGrannar
   A short fix I suggest:
   (I also removed some redundant lines)

   ```
     import java.util.Arrays;

     public class uppg10 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array1 = {{1, 1, 2, 3, 3},
            {2, 1, 1, 2, 3},
            {3, 2, 2, 1, 2},
            {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};

    int rows = array1.length;
    int cols = array1[0].length;

    boolean[][] array2 = new boolean[rows][cols];

    int totalavGrannar = 0;
    //Print array1
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%4d", array1[row][col]));
            if (((col + 1) % cols == 0) && (col > 0))
                System.out.println();
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

            if (array1[row][col] < 3)
                array2[row][col] = true;
            //Iterate neighbors to sum values
            for (int offsetRow = row - 1; offsetRow <= row + 1; offsetRow++) {
                for (int offsetCol = col - 1; offsetCol <= col + 1; offsetCol++) {

                    if (offsetRow >= 0 && offsetCol >= 0)   //0-bounds check
                        /*if (offsetRow < array1.length && offsetCol < array1.length) //edges-bounds check
                            if (offsetRow != row && offsetCol != col) {      //exclude position from sum
                                totalavGrannar += array1[offsetRow][offsetCol];
                            }*/
                        if (offsetRow < array1.length && offsetCol < array1[0].length) //edges-bounds check
                            if (offsetRow != row || offsetCol != col) {      //exclude position from sum
                                totalavGrannar += array1[offsetRow][offsetCol];
                            }
                }
            }
            if (totalavGrannar >= 15)
                array2[row][col] = false;
            totalavGrannar = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < array2.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array2[row].length; col++) {

            System.out.print(String.format("%8s", array2[row][col] ? "T" : "F"));
            if (((col + 1) % cols == 0) && (col > 0))

                System.out.println();

        }
    }
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: you sir, are a national treasure! I have one question though. Shouldn't for an example array1[3][4[ be printed as *F* with the given conditions? if (totalavGrannar >= 15)
                 array2[row][col] = false;

Comment: Yes, you right! I added fix in the code. See diff in /*comment*/ in the code